# Did the Skrulls actually precipitate any of the events leading up to the famous Civil War (and nearby) story-arcs?

Tags: marvel, avengers

In the build-up to the Invasion, there were several conversations featuring the Illuminati, the renegade Avengers of Luke Cage and others that mentioned that several recent cataclysmic events such as the Civil War, House of M etc. **felt** like *somebody was systematically pulling the strings.*  It was suggested that these were part of the Skrull invasion plans.

I've recently started re-reading a lot of these famous story-arcs but can't seem to piece together if any (and if so, WHICH) **key events** (that served to trigger/fuel these famous events mentioned above) were **actually** orchestrated by the Skrulls with their genetic-clone body-snatcher replacements of our heroes?

**Note** that this is a purely a comics canon question. I'm not asking about the TV series adaptation.

Answer (score 2):

While I can not think of direct influences by the skrulls remember that most were sleeper agents and did not know they were skrull. Although it is possible that they were more influencing the actions of the real key players. Examples could be Spider Woman and Jarvis helping to escalate tensions between Cap and Iron Man. Also, they did manage to infiltrate the Illuminati who's main purpose is to influence world events.